# how can i use icon or image to represent input type button

Tags: html, css, image, input, icons

How can I achieve displaying a icon or img for my input button.
Thanks

```
<input id="likebtn" name="likebtn" type="button">
```

I want to achieve something like this for my like button :

[image: i want to achieve something like this for my like button]

Comment: Have you tried `<input type="image">`?

Comment: no,i want  to display an icon for like button

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EWEwEZ

Comment: thanks for help, can it recieve  click event?

Comment: of course, it's an input field. it operates like `<input type="submit">` by default. You can give it a click handler to do whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks.. Pls can u help with a click handler to change the image on click.

Comment: I would recommend deleting this question and asking a new one. Also be more specific in your new question than you have been in this one. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

you can use the button tag like this:

```
<button type="button"> whatever text, img and/or icon</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this button css

```css
 button {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 134px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 104px;
}

#close-image img {
    display: block;
    height: 130px;  
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
And your button .
<button id="close-image"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/up2Fw.png"></button>
```